# Enable the input when click add new and Disable the input after click the create button

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an `<input>` and two `<button>`s. If I click `Add new input`, the `<input>` shows. However, I want to make the `<input>` disabled after the `Create` button is clicked. The `<input>` is working already, but it doesn't get disabled after clicking the `Create` button.

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button class="button is-orange has-text-white" @click="addRow">Add Input</button>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
          <td width="1%">{{++index}}</td>
          <td width="18%">
            <b-field>
              <input v-model="input.one" id="one" class="input one" type="text" placeholder>
            </b-field>
          </td>
          <td width="15%">
            <button class="button is-orange has-text-white" @click="inserts(inputs)">Create</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      searchorderid: null,
      inputs: [],
      data: {},
      loading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        one: ""
      });
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

I want the output to look like this:

[image: desired outcome]

After `Create` is clicked, the preceding `<input>` should be disabled.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-meadow-9mp3o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update `inserts()` to:

1. Receive the `input` iterator item (instead of `inputs`, which is already accessible via `this.inputs`):

   ```html
   <tr v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
     <!-- BEFORE -->
     <!-- <button @click="inserts(inputs)"> -->

     <button @click="inserts(input)">
       ...
     </button>
   </tr>
   ```
2. Add a Boolean prop to the `input` iterator item that indicates whether the corresponding `<input>` should be disabled:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       // BEFORE:
       //inserts(inputs) {

       inserts(input) {
         this.$set(input, 'disabled', true)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Bind `<input>`'s `disabled` prop to the newly added prop from the previous step:

   ```html
   <tr v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
     <input :disabled="input.disabled">
     ...
   </tr>
   ```

[image: Edit Disabling input inside v-for per item]

Comment: Thank you very much sir for answering. It did work. Really thank you a lot! =)